# Advanced URLs in Django

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls, django-mptt

The task is to write two url patterns.

The first one will take a single argument `<path>`, which can be any url with random depth:

`test/dorogi/`

or

`test/foo/bar/as/deep/as/you/want`

The second one will be the same as the first one, but with a number in the end.

`test/dorogi/1/`

It talkes two arguments: `<path>` and `<pk>`. The last one is a number.

---

I made a solution for the first pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/', mptt_urls.view(model='activities.models.Category', view='activities.views.category',
                                         slug_field='slug'), name='activities'),
```

But how do I make the second one and prevent any conflicts beteween them?

It should be something like:

```
url(r'^...', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
```

Comment: Just add this regex: '(?P<path>)(/\w+/?)+' match the first one, but should be in second place in url order. Second one more restrictive: '(?P<path>).*(/[0-9]+/?)$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the second parameter to the regex for the first pattern:

```
r'^(?P<path>.*)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'
```

But make sure to put that *before* the first one in your list of URLs.

(Note that you should definitely terminate your pattern with a $, as I did above.)

Comment: Yes. But then my url will look like `/articles/news/regional//4058/`. Notice that double slash before `pk`?